# Installing security patch error

Tags: error, ce-1.9.1.0, patches

I installed patch 1533 then 5344 both of them were for correct version.

When I was installing the second one 5344 it gave me error.

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
```

Do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the patches in following URL without using SSH 
https://www.milople.com/blogs/ecommerce/applying-magento-security-patch.html

Answer (score 2):

That particular error is for the 1533 - I had the same. It's likely that the magento you're using was downloaded after that patch was created 1533. Delving deeper into the patch, shows the file diffs are correct and already applied.

```
__PATCHFILE_FOLLOWS__
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
index c698108..6e256bb 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
@@ -444,7 +444,7 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboar
             }
             return self::API_URL . '?' . implode('&', $p);
         } else {
-            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(serialize($params)));
+            $gaData = urlencode(base64_encode(json_encode($params)));
             $gaHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
             $params = array('ga' => $gaData, 'h' => $gaHash);
             return $this->getUrl('*/*/tunnel', array('_query' => $params));
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
index eebb471..f9cb8d2 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
@@ -92,7 +92,8 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Actio
         if ($gaData && $gaHash) {
             $newHash = Mage::helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getChartDataHash($gaData);
             if ($newHash == $gaHash) {
-                if ($params = unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)))) {
+                $params = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($gaData)), true);
+                if ($params) {
                     $response = $httpClient->setUri(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Graph::API_URL)
                             ->setParameterGet($params)
                             ->setConfig(array('timeout' => 5))
```

Patch 5344 are applied on different files.